# Can I simplify the following zipped and zipWithIndex?

Tags: scala

```
def creditTransfer(invoices: List[Invoice], salons: List[Salon],
                   financialDetails: List[FinancialDetail]) = {
    // TODO: can the following be simplified? instead of having a
    // zipped and a zipWithIndex maybe one zip or something ...
    val creditTxnInforation = (invoices, salons, financialDetails)
    .zipped.toList.zipWithIndex.map {
      case ((invoice, salon, financialDetail), index) =>
        InvoiceToSepaConverter.toCreditTransactionDetail(
           invoice, salon, financialDetail, paymentId(pmtInfId, index))
    }
}
```

As the comment explains, I want to simplify zipped and zipWithIndex.

Comment: " I want to simplify zipped and zipWithIndex." Why? it seems clear enough now

Answer (score 2):

Turn the payment IDs into an iterable so you can shove the indexing concept off to the side, and zip up all four iterables at once.

Not sure if this is exactly right since I don't have enough of your code to compile it, but something along these lines:

```
def creditTransfer(invoices: List[Invoice], salons: List[Salon],
                   financialDetails: List[FinancialDetail]) = {
  val paymentIds = Stream.from(0).map(paymentId(pmtInfId, _))
  val creditTxnInforation =
    (invoices, salons, financialDetails, paymentIds).zipped
      .map((InvoiceToSepaConverter.toCreditTransactionDetail _).tupled)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the suggested refactoring.